# VLC coding and display

Tags: c, windows, libvlc, m3u8

I'm using `libvlc` to display the video stream after capturing the `ts` fragments exposed by `m3u8` index files. I have never used `libvlc` before. According some tutorials, the following lines:

```
    libvlc_instance_t* inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t* mp;
    libvlc_media_t* m;
    
    inst=libvlc_new(0,NULL);
    m=libvlc_media_new_path(inst,"...");
    mp=libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    
    libvlc_media_release(m);
    
    //For windows. binding the displaying window.
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(mp,hwnd);
    
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
    Sleep(3000);
    
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);
```

It seems you just need to call few functions and set some parameters for some initialization and then binding the window to display the video resource, libvlc should know how to do the coding and decoding works and display the stream. After all of those works done, release the resource. Sound pretty convenient.

After following those codes, the window just flickered once and exited. I don't know why yet.

My code is something like this:

```
int test(HWND hwnd)
{
    //const char* version=libvlc_get_version();
    //const char* compiler=libvlc_get_compiler();
    //const char* changeset=libvlc_get_changeset();
    
    //printf("Libvlc.\n");
    //printf("Version:%s\n",version);
    //printf("Compiler:%s\n",compiler);
    //printf("Changeset:%s\n",changeset);
    
    libvlc_instance_t* inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t* mp;
    libvlc_media_t* m;
    
    inst=libvlc_new(0,NULL);
    m=libvlc_media_new_path(inst,"my video resource file path...");
    mp=libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    
    libvlc_media_release(m);
    
    //For windows. binding the displaying window.
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(mp,hwnd);
    
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
    Sleep(3000);
    
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);
    
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hprevinstance, PSTR szcmdLine, int icmdshow)
{
    HWND hwnd=NULL;
    
    InitCommonControls();
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    
    if(Frame_Register(hinstance)!=0) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"window register failed","Sorry",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    if(NULL==(hwnd=Frame_Create(hinstance,1200,600))) return 0;
    
    Frame_Test(hwnd);
    
    return Frame_Run(hwnd);
}

int regist_window(char* class_name,HINSTANCE instance,WNDPROC proc)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass;

    wndclass.cbSize=sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style = CS_DBLCLKS|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = proc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = instance;
    wndclass.hIcon = NULL;
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = class_name;
    wndclass.hIconSm = NULL;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wndclass)) return -1;
    return 0;
}

HWND Frame_Create(HINSTANCE instance,int width,int height)
{
    int cx,cy;
    POINT pt;
    
    cx=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    cy=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    
    pt.x=(cx-width)>>1;
    pt.y=(cy-height)>>1;
    
    HWND hwnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                             WINDOW_CLASS_NAME,
                             "Docker Frame Capture",
                             WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE|WS_HSCROLL|WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                             pt.x,pt.y,width,height,NULL,
                             (HMENU)NULL,
                             instance,NULL);

    // Some owner-drawing and data referring to the customized window.
    Frame_InitialSettings(hwnd);
    
    return hwnd;
}

int Frame_Run(HWND frame)
{
    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)) {
        if(!IsDialogMessage(frame,&msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    
    return(msg.wParam);
}

int Frame_Test(HWND hwnd)
{
    //create a child window , as a container for vlc player.
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);
    int width=rc.right-rc.left,height=rc.bottom-rc.top;
    
    HWND vlc_hwnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                             WC_STATIC,
                             "",
                             WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                             0,0,width,height,hwnd,
                             (HMENU)NULL,//LoadMenu(instance,"IDR_FRMENU"),
                             (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWLP_HINSTANCE),NULL);
    
    test(vlc_hwnd);
    return 0;
}
```

New addings:
the function `libvlc_new` return null, `libvlc_errmsg()` return null string.

Modified 7th July:
Problem figured out, You must copy the plugsin folder of `libvlc` to your project.
[image]

Comment: you need to parse the m3u and play one of its subitems

Comment: nothing referring to m3u8 yet, just libvlc, ```libvlc_new``` return null, don't know why

Comment: I think I know what's going on.  When you use ```libvlc``` sdk, pay attention to the folder plugsin

Comment: if libvlc_new returns null, it means it cannot find your plugins

Comment: how did you install libvlc?

Comment: @mfkl ,yeah,  I later figured it out, plugsin folder must be copied to the project